# How to set compound structure for two different layers if I used 2 different categories of material for wall structure , using revit api

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to create a wall with 2 layers and each layer materials are different. When I try to set the `CompoundStructure` for the wall I am getting an exception that `CompoundStructure` is not valid.

```
CompoundStructure cStructure = CompoundStructure.CreateSimpleCompoundStructure(clayer);
wallType.SetCompoundStructure(cStructure);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can create compound structure for layers with different materials?

Comment: before setting the compound structure to try validate the compound structure and then set it. if the compound structure is not valid then it will give you error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newWallMaterial = wallMaterial.Duplicate("newCreatedMaterial");
                newWallmaterial2 = wallMaterial.Duplicate("NewCreatedMAterial2");
                //roofMaterial3 = roofMaterial2.Duplicate("NewCreatedMAterial3");

                bool usr = newWallMaterial.UseRenderAppearanceForShading;
                    //newWallMaterial.Color = BuiltInTypeParam.materialCol;


                foreach (Layers layer in layers)
                {
                    if (layer.layerId == 0)
                    {
                        c = new CompoundStructureLayer(layer.width, layer.materialAssignement, newWallMaterial.Id);
                        newWallMaterial.Color = color;
                        clayer.Add(c);
                    }
                    if (layer.layerId == 1)
                    {
                        c1 = new CompoundStructureLayer(layer.width, layer.materialAssignement, newWallmaterial2.Id);
                        newWallmaterial2.Color = color;
                        clayer.Add(c1);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, solve your task manually through the end user interface and verify that it works at all.

Then, use RevitLookup and other database exploration tools to examine the results in the BIM elements, their properties and relationships.

Once you have done that, you will have a good idea how to address the task programmatically – and have confidence that it will work as expected:

- [How to research to find a Revit API solution](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/virtues-of-reproduction-research-mep-settings-ontology.html#3)
- [Intimate Revit database exploration with the Python Shell](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/11/intimate-revit-database-exploration-with-the-python-shell.html)

Comment: Thanks  jeremy Tammik for Reply . I just solve my issue By creating new material              
                                                                                                                               Thanks!